# How to make Modbus RTU RS485 on cape comms2 works on the Beaglebone black?

Tags: debian, serial-port, beagleboneblack

I am scratching my head for days now, trying to make Modbus RTU RS 485 working on my Beaglebone black having the cape comms2 set and running Debian.

I connect to `/dev/ttyS0` at 9600 bauds, 8-bit data, 1-bit stop, no parity with my nodeJS sw as follows:

```javascript
            let SerialPort = require("serialport");
            let serialport = new SerialPort(this.device, { autoOpen: false, baudRate: 9600, stopbits: 1, databits: 8, parity: 'none' }, false);

            this.log('Opening serial connection… (client = ModbusRTU())')
            const client = new ModbusRTU(serialport)
            this.success('client is', client)
            this.log("Port Open Status: " + client.isOpen);
            client.open()

            // set a timout for requests default is null (no timeout)
            client.setTimeout(2e3)

            setInterval(() => {
                this.log("Port Open Status: " + client.isOpen);
                if (!client.isOpen) return

                run()

            },10e3)

            var i=0
            const run = () => {
                this.success(`Connected!`)

                this.success('--> Running…')
                if (i&1) read()
                else write()

                i++
                
                this.log('<-- Leaving run, but wait for the response in the future call back…')
            }

            /**
             * Read the RS485 packet: start adress 0x0C count 1 register
             */
            const read = () => {
                // read the 2 registers starting at address 5
                // on device number 1.
                this.log('About to read, setting the ID to 0xD2…')
                client.setID(0xD2)
                this.log('Now reading 1 register from start address 0x2A, wait for the response…')
                client
                //.readHoldingRegisters()
                .readHoldingRegisters(0x2A, 1)
                .then(args => this.log('Received SoC:', ...args))
                .catch(err => this.error('Received eror:', err))
                .finally(() => this.log('Received: finally'))

            }


            /**
             * Write to the RS485 register
             */
            const write = () => {
                // write the values 0, 0xffff to registers starting at address 5
                // on device number 1.
                //this.log('Writing: 0xD2, [0x03, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x01, 0x57, 0xAA,]')
                this.log('Writing: FC3 0xD2,0x2A,1')
                client.setID(0xD2)
                if (true) {
                    client
                    .writeFC3(0x06,0x2A, 1, (err, data) => {
                        if (err) {
                            this.error('writeFC3:', err)
                        } else {
                            this.success('writeFC3:', data)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
```

And I get the logs like so:

```bsh
Pepsr v2.2.236 9:56:14 AM  [pepsr-olenlab2]  -- -  Modbus: setup(installation) is not supercharged, this.installation is set to undefined
Pepsr v2.2.236 9:56:14 AM  [pepsr-olenlab2]  -- ---  Modbus: Connecting to modbus/serial:///dev/ttyS0 at 9600 bauds…
Pepsr v2.2.236 9:56:14 AM  [pepsr-olenlab2]  -- ---  Modbus: Opening serial connection… (client = ModbusRTU())
Pepsr v2.2.236 9:56:14 AM  [pepsr-olenlab2]  -- ✅-  Modbus: client is ModbusRTU {

Pepsr v2.2.236 9:56:24 AM  [pepsr-olenlab2]  -- ---  Modbus: Port Open Status: true
Pepsr v2.2.236 9:56:24 AM  [pepsr-olenlab2]  -- ✅-  Modbus: Connected!
Pepsr v2.2.236 9:56:24 AM  [pepsr-olenlab2]  -- ✅-  Modbus: --> Running…
Pepsr v2.2.236 9:56:24 AM  [pepsr-olenlab2]  -- ---  Modbus: Writing: FC3 0xD2,0x2A,1
Pepsr v2.2.236 9:56:24 AM  [pepsr-olenlab2]  -- ---  Modbus: <-- Leaving run, but wait for the response in the future call back…
Pepsr v2.2.236 9:56:26 AM  [pepsr-olenlab2]  -- -  Modbus: writeFC3: TransactionTimedOutError {
  name: 'TransactionTimedOutError',
  message: 'Timed out',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT'
}
```

As you can see I got timeout which suggest I maybe not connected to the right device. I tried to tie minicom to the device but this let the screen empty.

[UPDATE]

Another way I tried to send/received data to/from the RS485 by doing this on a terminal:

`$ sudo cat /dev/ttyS0`

And from another one, from my script:

`$ sudo ./serialSend.sh 0`

Where my script `serialSend.sh` is:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
DEVICE=/dev/ttyS$1

stty -F $DEVICE speed 9600 cs8 -parenb -echo
echo -en "\xD2\x03\x00\x0C\x01\x57\xAA" > $DEVICE
```

But I got nothing. I tried with all 6 devices, from 0 to 5.

This is why I wanted to get help about how to:

1. check that /dev/ttyS0 is the right device to talk to?
2. how can I send packet from a tool as hex code such as: D2 03 00 0C 00 01 57 AA?

Anyone with beaglebone xp is welcome!

The Modbus RTU RS 485 doc I have is as follows (translated from Chinese by Google translate) :

| 数据格式:9600 8位数据 1位停止位 无校验 / Data format: 9600 8-bit data, 1 stop bit, no parity |
| --- |
| "支持modbus协议 3 6 16 数据格式为高位在前,低位在后 |
| Support modbus protocol 3 6 16 The data format is high order first, low order last" |
| 报文协议格式：读寄存器，请求帧 / Message protocol format: read register, request frame |
| BYTE 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 |
| 字段定义 / Field definition ADDR CMD MSB LSB MSB LSB CRC-L CRC-H |
| 描述 /description 0xD2 0x03 寄存器起始地址 寄存器个数N CRC-16校验 |
| "说明：D2 03 00 0C 00 01 57 AA |
| D2是从机地址，03是读命令，000C是寄存器起始地址，0001意为读取寄存器数量为1，即读取命令，57AA是CRC校验码。 |
| D2 is the slave address, 03 is the read command, 000C is the register start address, 0001 means that the number of read registers is 1, that is, the read command, and 57AA is the CRC check code." |

Comment: any luck of this thing? for echo command you need to add "-e" args, eg: `echo -e "\xA0"`

Comment: @MochamadArifin Well, not much. The situation I have now is that on somme BBB it works. But other it does not. Or even  more weird, it may stop working on a given BBB. Do you have experience on those thing we can share?

Comment: I just started and still not work..

Comment: @MochamadArifin Anything new on your side? Regarding the setup I asked this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/686312/troubleshooting-rs485-comm-on-beaglebone-black-with-cape-comms2

Comment: I have nodejs background, may I will try it on free time..

Comment: @MochamadArifin Anything new?